# Problems with Arduino libraries in the Eclipse environment (__vector_XX)

Tags: eclipse-cdt, arduino, avr

I'm trying to migrate an Arduino IDE based project to Eclipse. The project is pretty big (10 .pde's, and about 20 libraries used). I followed the directions in *[Arduino playground - Eclipse](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/Eclipse)* to compile the core libraries and to create a base project. All compiles very well when testing it with a simple LED-blink program.

For my application to work I also needed some more libraries (standard Arduino libraries, for example, SoftwareSerial, SPI, or Wire) and custom ones. I imported them like I did with the core library above (I created two more projects) and compiled them. All worked nicely.

After importing all .pde's to the base project in Eclipse, converting them to classes and cleaning up the code a little bit the last problem I can't get rid of are multiple variable definitions, causing errors like this:

```
./src/main.o: In function `__vector_37':
main.cpp:(.text.__vector_37+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_37'
./src/MyClass.o:MyClass.cpp:(.text.__vector_37+0x0): first defined here
```

The point is, I cannot find any __vector_XX variables anywhere in my code or included libraries with grep. Eclipse's hints regarding where to look for the cause also don't help much. What should I do?

Comment: Seems to be a problem in your code (main.pde, MyClass.pde). To help you we need to have a look at these files.

Comment: I'd rather say it's a problem with Arduino libraries not being built with ArduinoIDE, as Arduino uses some funny make logic. I know some people may be familiar with those __vector_ errors, just haven't found a way of solving those anywhere.

Comment: Have a look at the error message. It says there are two different definitions, one in `main.o` and the other in `MyClass.o`. Neither of them is part of any library. Maybe the problem is in an include file that's used in both files.

Comment: Of course, you're generally right, there is a problem of conflicting definitions of __vector_37 in both files. But the problem is also Arduino-specific. I just found a hint I didn't see before [click](http://freaklabs.org/index.php/Forum/Chibi-General/2680-freakduino-gps-and-NewSoftSerial-library-conflict.html). So I guess I built some libraries which both use same interrupts.

Comment: I guess you're working with an Arduino Mega, 'cause there is no ISR vector 37 on the ATmega328. On the ATmega1280 vector 37 means `USART1 Data register Empty`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm indeed working with ATmega1280. Where do I find information about what which vector means?

Comment: You can find a description in the datasheet (http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc2549.pdf). The C++ definitions are in the include file `iomxx0_1.h`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Taken from @mmm's link in the question comments]:

[Fix for a similar issue](http://freaklabs.org/index.php/Forum/Chibi-General/2680-freakduino-gps-and-NewSoftSerial-library-conflict.html).

Comment: You're right, I should have marked this as solved somehow :).